# Creating a synchronized list in golang

Tags: concurrency, go

Firstly, forgive me if this is a stupid question.
I would like to create a generic synchronised list (like in Java) for reuse in my Go projects.
I found the source of Go's [linked list](https://golang.org/src/container/list/list.go?m=text) and I was wondering would it be sufficient to simply add mutex locks to the list manipulation functions?

Comment: A thread like this one (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/PWU3f3i5ziY) suggests that the intended usage for that thread-safe list is important, and can help choosing from the various synchronization methods.

Comment: Can't a buffered channel be used for this? Apart from being statically sized it's just  a synchronized FIFO list.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'm not sure I could use a buffered channel because I want to remove and search items in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to make a concurrent-safe container, you need to protect *all* access to the data, not just writes. Inspecting an element, or even calling `Len()` without synchronizing the read could return invalid or corrupt data.

It's probably easier to protect the entire data structure with a mutex, rather than implement your own concurrent linked list.

Comment: Yes, it's not too often one actually needs a doubly-linked-list, especially a concurrent one for reuse in various projects.

Comment: @3of3 a Slice protected by a mutex was exactly what I originally had in mind.

Comment: I think this answer would be better with example code.